pip kills installation process but there is memory available
In this question they mention that when pip shows killed process is due to memory problems. I checked on this link and when I run it in powershell it shows:
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on  
/dev/sdc       1007G   47G  910G   5% /mnt/wslg/distro

And in the file explorer it shows that I still have 78 GB of memory in C:
Even though, when I run
pip install torch 

inside a virtual environment inside wsl, it shows
Collecting torch
Downloading torch-2.4.1-cp310-cp310-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (797.1 MB)
 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━╸ 797.0/797.1 MB 1.7 MB/s eta 0:00:01Killed


/dev/sdc is not memory, it's your disk, your permanent storage. When a process is killed due to memory constraints it's RAM. Not enough RAM, To see how much RAM you have use command free -h.
